# Magento 2 - Website Store View strategy

Tags: magento2

We have an eshop in 3 different countries (3 domains) domain.lng1 domain.lng2 domain.lng3
Plus each country has optional language EN

- domain.lng1/lgn1/
- domain.lng1/EN/
- domain.lng2/lgn2/
- domain.lng2/EN/
- domain.lng3/lgn3/
- domain.lng3/EN/

All countries has the same products. In rare occasion we want to disable product (make it out of stock) for particular country.
Prices and shipping options are also the same but flexibility to have different per country would be good.

How should we set up our M2 Websites / Stores / Views to best fit this model?